# Compare and sort array using javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

For the following

```
array1 = [{
        "x": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "z": 1,
        "i": "chart1"
         }, {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 1,
        "i": "chart2"
         }, {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1,
        "z": 1,
        "i": "chart3 "
    }
]

array2 = [{
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1,
        "z": 1,
        "i": "chart1"
        }, {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "z": 1,
        "i": "chart2"
        }, {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 1,
        "i": "chart3"
    }
]
```

compare `x` and `y` of `array1` and `array2` and find the position if it is equal and return the set of array of i value.

i.e in above case it should return:

```
array3=["chart2","chart3","chart1"]
```

I have a json as below:

```
json = [{
        "visType:" bar "," visName ":" chart1 "},{" visType: "bar",
        "visName": "chart2"
    }, {
        "visType:" Pie "," visName ":" chart3 "}]
```

And this need to be sort based on `array3 = ["chart2","chart3","chart1"]` the output should be as in updated json

```
updatedjson = [{
        "visType:" bar "," visName ":" chart2 "},{" visType: "Pie",
        "visName": "chart3"
    }, {
        "visType:" bar "," visName ":" chart1 "}]
```

I need a solution using `lodash` or `javascript`.

Comment: Before anything, reformat the code in this question.

Comment: what you have tried please share the codebase we will look into it. thanks

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
const array3 = [...array1, ...array2].filter(({x,y}) => x===y);
const updatedjson = array3.map(({i}) => json.find(({visName}) => i === visName));
```

Edit: Fixed the input data which was full of syntax errors:

```
var array1 = [{ "x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 1, "i": "chart1" }, { "x": 0, "y": 2, "z": 1, "i": "chart2" }, { "x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 1, "i": "chart3" }];
var array2 = [{ "x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 1, "i": "chart1" }, { "x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 1, "i": "chart2" }, { "x": 0, "y": 2, "z": 1, "i": "chart3" }];

var json = [
    { "visType": "bar", "visName": "chart1" },
    { "visType": "bar", "visName": "chart2" },
    { "visType": "Pie", "visName": "chart3" }
];

const array3 = [...array1, ...array2].filter(({ x, y }) => x === y);
const updatedjson = array3.map(({ i }) => json.find(({ visName }) => i === visName));
console.log(array3);
console.log(updatedjson);
```

Comment: Did i pass the class? xD

Comment: No the answer is not matching :)

Comment: Yes it does. Your input data is all messed up & full of syntax errors like missing quotes. Once you fix those, my code works ;)